# How do I make panic use my structured logging format?

Tags: go

I want to be able to just `panic(err)` and have panic output in my `slog` format for my log aggregation.

I'll I need is for the full output and stack trace of panic to be nested in my logs `msg` field.

Is it possible to do this without a bunch of custom handling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can log the panic in a simple way by setting the default logger to your `slog` logger. The drawback is that everything logged in this way will be logged at the `INFO` level and the stack trace will not be included.

```golang
    slogger := slog.New(slog.NewJSONHandler(os.Stdout, nil))
    slog.SetDefault(slogger)

    slogger.Info("just some info")
    log.Panic("unrecoverable error")
```

Will output:

```
{"time":"2009-11-10T23:00:00Z","level":"INFO","msg":"just some info"}
{"time":"2009-11-10T23:00:00Z","level":"INFO","msg":"unrecoverable error"}
panic: unrecoverable error
...
<panic output>
...
```

Comment: I was about to close as a dup for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60516923/logging-unhandled-golang-panics. But this info is also useful so I'll leave my post open unless its voted down.